# Incrementing an int via a button returns unintended behavior.

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a variable that i wish to increment. If i do it like this, it works fine:

```
var curTrial = 0;

function inc(x) {
    x++;
    return x;
    }

function show () {
    document.write(curTrial)
    curTrial = inc(curTrial);
    }

show();show();show();show()
```

This results in `0123`, as expected/intended.

However, if i spice it up a little with a button, it'll behave strangely.

```
<html>    
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>      
</head>
<body>

<div id="box" style="text-align:center">
    <div id="startTrial">Press any key to start the next trial</div>
      <button id="next"type="button">Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
  var curTrial = 0;

function inc(x) {
    x++;
    return x;
    }

function RunTrial() {

     prompt(curTrial);
     curTrial = inc(curTrial);
     $('#box').show();
     $("#next").click(function(f) { StartExperiment(); });
}
function StartExperiment() {
    $('#box').show();
    $("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); });   
}
StartExperiment()
 </script>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the value still increments with one at a time, but i would expect it to be called once for each button press. Instead, it appears to be called double the amount of last time (once, twice, four times, eight times etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching a `click` event handler each time inside the function RunTrial() and `StartExperiment()`

**Sloution**

1. Remove the event handlers from the funtion and put them in `$(document).ready` block.
2. Use `$("#next").unbind( "click" );` to unbind the event.

Well first one is preferable.

```js
var curTrial = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); });
});

function inc(x) {
    x++;
    return x;
}

function RunTrial() {

     prompt(curTrial);
     curTrial = inc(curTrial);
     $('#box').show();
     $("#next").click(function(f) { StartExperiment(); });
}
function StartExperiment() {
    $('#box').show();
}
StartExperiment();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>    
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>      
</head>
<body>

<div id="box" style="text-align:center">
    <div id="startTrial">Press any key to start the next trial</div>
      <button id="next"type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in `RunTrial()`, you call `StartExperiment()`, which adds a new click listener to the `#next` button, so every time you click it, you're adding on a new click listener. If you just remove that line, you'll see that it works as intended (only one prompt per click).

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'click listener'?

Comment: When you use `$("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); })`, you're adding a callback function. When the button is clicked, it will fire off a `click` event. Any callback functions registered to that particular event will be invoked. You can add multiple callback functions to the same event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var curTrial = 0;

function inc(x) {
    x++;
    return x;
    }

function RunTrial() {

     curTrial=prompt(curTrial);
     curTrial = inc(curTrial);
     $('#box').show();
     $("#next").click(function(f) { StartExperiment(); });
}
function StartExperiment() {
    $('#box').show();
    $("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); });   
}
StartExperiment()
```

```html
<html>    
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>      
</head>
<body>

<div id="box" style="text-align:center">
    <div id="startTrial">Press any key to start the next trial</div>
      <button id="next"type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `$("#next").click(function(f) { StartExperiment(); });` from runTrial() function.
What you are doing is binding a click event everytime RunTrial() is called.
clicking on submit button, will trigger runTrial function as many times the number of click events binded to it.
Just bind the event once and it will work everytime the button is clicked